# can we use use "all day" in all aspects of past tense?

Tags: tense

Look at the following sentences:

> 1. It rained all day yesterday so I stayed indoors
> 2. It was raining all day yesterday so I stayed indoors
> 3. It had been raining all day yesterday so I stayed indoors

Are all the sentences correct? If yes, what is the difference in meaning?

What are the possible expressions with "all day" in other tenses?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

"all day" is acting as an adverb, giving us more information about "raining".

To show the pattern, here's an alternative adverb.

> it was raining heavily so I stayed in doors.

The differences between the three phrases are to do with the tenses. Try each phrase without the all day:

> It rained yesterday so I stayed indoors
>
> It was raining yesterday so I stayed indoors

These two work without the "all day", but adding "all day" intensifies the feeling, the rain was occurring all day, no opportunity to go out.

> It had been raining yesterday

Without the "all day" has a feeling of incompleteness, a sense that the rain stopped after some time. So adding "all day" strongly clarifies that there was rain for the entire day.